# Error in findElement function in RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to run this code:

```
library(RSelenium)

pJS<- phantom()

remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")

url<- "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-rent/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Service-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa&cityName=Mumbai"

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(url)

webElem1 <- remDr$findElement("name", ">5 BHK")

webElem2 <- remDr$findElement("css", "#refinebedrooms li:nth-child(6)")

webElem3 <- remDr$findElement("css", "#viewMoreButton a")
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Error:      Summary: NoSuchElement
>   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
>   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
>        Further Details: run errorDetails method

What does this mean? And how can I overcome it? I am new to R and a first time user of RSelenium so any kind of help would be much appreciated? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are new I would strongly recommend to go over the help file [R-SELENIUM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf) and then try using the package.

The element with name >5 BHK does not exist. And that is the reason you are getting an error. but the webElem2 is the same as webElem1(if this worked).

So to answer your question, you have to identify where the error occurs. and the error is pretty self-explanatory. `NoSuchElement`.

So one of your three webelements1,2,3 is not seen in the page by the webdriver. If you want to identify the elements using `css` assuming you are new to HTML too, I would suggest you to use [Selector gadget](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYnrCZ-eHPAhUq4YMKHU97DMsQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fselectorgadget%2Fmhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb&usg=AFQjCNFf32oI9iQPGe6WRfrKIWa-23n-xg) to identify the element using `css` or `xpath`